# How to enable openCL rendering in Blender 2.75 rc2

Tags: rendering, gpu, linux, opencl

I'm using Linux Mint and I was trying to enable GPU rendering, but I still have only CPU option in user preferences...

- Linux Mint 17.1 x64
- Radeon HD 7850
- Blender 2.75 rc2
- amd-catalyst 15.5

*solved by myself*

Comment: Maybe this is useful :) : https://anteru.net/2014/08/24/2500/

Comment: thank you, but i seen that and it's not working for me, that's why i'm here

Comment: what have you tried to get it working? have you read the GPU guide http://blender.org/manual/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html ?

Comment: i was trying to set up environment variables ( CYCLES_OPENCL_SPLIT_KERNEL_TEST=1, and CYCLES_OPENCL_TEST=all ), running Blender as root, installing Blender from software center and repeat same. yes i read that before (GPU guide)

Answer (score 2):

I have found solution to my problem. To enable openCl on Linux Mint 17.1 with ATI radeon video card just install **`ocl-icd-libopencl1`** package for 64 bit system, or **`ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386`** for 32 bit system. No need to run Blender as root or set up environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu open the Terminal and do:

```
 sudo apt-get install ocl-icd-opencl-dev
```

then:

```
CYCLES_OPENCL_SPLIT_KERNEL_TEST=1 blender
```